# Converting bytebuffer to string not working in java

Tags: java, decode, bytebuffer

In runtime am getting a bytebuffer data from a device, Am trying to decode that data to read the contents of it.

When I print the bytebuffer using string it shows as follows,

```
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3]
```

I tried to decode using all the known formats as follows,

```
       CharBuffer charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(paramByteBuffer);
       String text = charBuffer.toString();
       System.out.println("UTF-8"+text); 
       charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_16.decode(paramByteBuffer);
       text = charBuffer.toString();
       System.out.println("UTF_16"+text); 
       charBuffer = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.decode(paramByteBuffer);
       text = charBuffer.toString();
       System.out.println("ISO_8859_1"+text); 
       charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE.decode(paramByteBuffer);
       text = charBuffer.toString();
       System.out.println("UTF_16BE"+text); 
       charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE.decode(paramByteBuffer);
       text = charBuffer.toString();
       System.out.println("UTF_16LE"+text); 
       charBuffer = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.decode(paramByteBuffer);
       text = charBuffer.toString();
       System.out.println("US_ASCII"+text);
```

Everything returns the empty data.

What are the ways to decode the byte buffer data?

Comment: What is `paramByteBuffer`? And what is in it?

Comment: Its a byte buffer data, But not sure of the format.

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
String val = new String(paramByteBuffer.array());
```

OR

```
String val = new String(paramByteBuffer.array(),"UTF-8");
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) is a list of supported charsets

Answer (score 6):

Buffers are a little tricky to use as they have a current state, which you need to take into account when accessing them.

you want to put

```
 paramByteBuffer.flip();
```

before each decode to get the buffer into the state you want for the decode to read.

e.g.

```
ByteBuffer paramByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
paramByteBuffer.put((byte)'a');  // write 'a' at next position(0)
paramByteBuffer.put((byte)'b');  // write 'b' at next position(1)
paramByteBuffer.put((byte)'c');  // write 'c' at next position(2)

// if I try to read now I will read the next byte position(3) which is empty
// so I need to flip the buffer so the next position is at the start
paramByteBuffer.flip();          

// we are at position 0 so we can do our read function
CharBuffer charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(paramByteBuffer);
String text = charBuffer.toString();
System.out.println("UTF-8" + text);

// because the decoder has read all the written bytes we are back to the
// state (position 3) we had just after we wrote the bytes in the first 
// place so we need to flip again 
paramByteBuffer.flip();

// we are now at position 0 so we can do our read function
charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_16.decode(paramByteBuffer);
text = charBuffer.toString();
System.out.println("UTF_16"+text);
```

Comment: Still, its returning only some junk symbol.

Comment: You should expect that. Different charsets have different values for each character.

Comment: You need to know which charset the data has been encoded with.

Answer (score 1):

The [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#toString--) method of `HeapByteBuffer` simply

> Returns a string summarizing the state of this buffer.

In other words, it returns

```
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=3 cap=3]
```

which shows the byte buffer's position, limit, and capacity.

In this case, your `ByteBuffer` has capacity for 3 more bytes. Each `Charset#decode` call consumes the `ByteBuffer` and you don't [rewind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind--)/[reset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#reset--) it so there are no more bytes to consume for subsequent calls. In other words, all those strings will be empty.